# How to grep command line argument on which RegEx has been applied?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, regular-expression, arguments

I'm trying to write a script that takes as input a set of integers representing certain `/dev/sda`'s. For example, if the command line arguments are 3 & 5, the output will show the UUID for `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5`. My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

### Shows UUID of input /dev's - REQUIRES SUDO

## Options:
## [-m] Multiple Devs   - returns both dev name and UUID
## [  ] No option       - returns only the UUID of the dev.

while getopts m: option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
    m)  echo -e "\nDEV\tUUID\n====\t================"
        blkid | grep .*sda[\"$@\"] | sed -r 's/\/dev\/([[:alnum:]]+).* UUID="([[:alnum:]]+)".*/\1\t\2/g'
        ;;
    esac
done
```

My primary problem is with the line `grep .*sda[\"$@\"]` which returns the following error:

$ sudo ./dUShow.sh -m 3 5

```
DEV     UUID
====    ================
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
```

Now if I'm not mistaken, this means the problem occurs when I'm trying to provide as alternative options `*.sda[$@]` which I want RegEx to overwrite with `*.sda[$1$2]`, equivalent to `*.sda[35]` for the given input.

How do I do this?

## Sample Input

```
sudo ./dUShow.sh -m 3 5
```

## Desired output

```
DEV     UUID
====    ================
sda3    BC4208CF42089076
sda5    968E185A8E183569
```

### Addendum

Is the expression `.*sda[\"$@\"]` going to produce `*.sda[35]` or `*.sda[3 5]`? If it is the latter, will it cause a problem? If so, how do I solve it?

Comment: I would add -E to your grep command for a start

Comment: @RamanSailopal Really doesn't help at all! Why does this grep need Extended RegEx anyway?

Comment: First, `sed` doesn't need `grep` and second, to get the device name and UUID you definitely don't need `blkid` (nor root access for that matter): `man lsblk` is your friend... and btw, _OR_-ing patterns is done via `|`

Comment: @don_crissti thanks for the suggestions, but any way I could make this present script work?

Comment: Instead of doing the wrong thing the wrong way you should build up the command line arguments (e.g args like `/dev/sd[a-z][0-9]+` and so on...) and then replace that entire nonsense with `lsblk -o name,uuid "$@"`. A [typical case of XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $1==3 and $2==5 then

```
grep .*sda[\"$@\"]
```

turns into

```
grep .*sda[3 5]
```

Which is a problem due to the lack of quotes. Try this instead:

```
regex=".*sda($( IFS='|'; echo "$*" ))\\>"     # => .*sda(3|5)\>
blkid | grep -E "$regex" | ...
```

The `\>` is a word boundary, to make the regex more precise.

---

Some documentation about GNU grep regular expression flavours:

1. [basic regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html#grep-regular-expression-syntax)
2. [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html#egrep-regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! 

Could you please explain the line `".*sda($( IFS='|'; echo "$*" ))"`?

Comment: If you `echo "$regex"` you can see the result. `"$*"` joins the positional parameters using the first char of IFS as the separator. I do that in a subshell to avoid changing IFS in the current shell

Answer (score 1):

For single digit matches you can put the argument string straight into the RE brackets. (I think this is what you were originally trying to do.)

```
grep "/dev/sda[$*]:"
```

Note that `$*` will include a space character between digit arguments (for example, `2` and `5` will result in `$*` having the quoted value `2 5`), but as we can guarantee that `/dev/sda :` will never match it doesn't matter in this situation.

To simplify the command line you can then dispense entirely with the `grep`, like this:

```
blkid | sed -rn "s#/dev/(sda[$*]):"'.* UUID="([[:alnum:]]+)".*#\1\t\2#p'
```